# how to embed youtube channel video on website with php

Tags: php, iframe, youtube, embed, youtube-channels

after the youtube api v3 update I don't know how to repair the video section of my site.
The section shows videos uploaded in my youtube channel UCBL3ecWukz_EX7FrDmtdgJQ

I already created OAuth: Client ID for web application ,Public API access: Key for server applications and Key for browser applications.

Now I'm trying to understand how to use them to retrieve a list of the videos uploaded on my channel.

I tried this code

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCBL3ecWukz_EX7FrDmtdgJQ&maxResults=20&key=***************************************
```

now I don't know what to do with the output..
something like that

```js
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/6M9Lo8BzT3ingng1jJF2bBh1CNs\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 5,
  "resultsPerPage": 20
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/LHUK9eLdq9H2-Szizgc5BvV-gxM\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCBL3ecWukz_EX7FrDmtdgJQ"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2014-12-26T11:20:46.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBL3ecWukz_EX7FrDmtdgJQ",
    "title": "Parrocchia Sant'Agata Alì",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-O78yDecTsmk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/U-NQ4NkzZQE/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-O78yDecTsmk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/U-NQ4NkzZQE/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-O78yDecTsmk/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/U-NQ4NkzZQE/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/YPX-4TZwL2BMwOoIP3pO2_KBzvs\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "FjGA6cjh5zI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-12T23:45:39.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBL3ecWukz_EX7FrDmtdgJQ",
    "title": "Alì S  Agata Bacio del braccio",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FjGA6cjh5zI/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FjGA6cjh5zI/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/FjGA6cjh5zI/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/-m38lEymXlK8ZVMm2dNRzX8e8ro\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "7PQBjOedbtk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-07T20:43:40.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBL3ecWukz_EX7FrDmtdgJQ",
    "title": "Annuncio Festa Grande",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7PQBjOedbtk/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7PQBjOedbtk/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7PQBjOedbtk/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/Bv1fyl1c4aVHIrWuOV5gNf7xpMI\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "Gmelq3hGEPI"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-02-15T23:17:22.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBL3ecWukz_EX7FrDmtdgJQ",
    "title": "Alì S  Agata riposta sull'altare",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Gmelq3hGEPI/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Gmelq3hGEPI/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Gmelq3hGEPI/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"iDqJ1j7zKs4x3o3ZsFlBOwgWAHU/LZFjbm4TuWdxvls0Jzan6H6Ow5A\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "GMizgWpyt2k"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-03-27T22:13:32.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCBL3ecWukz_EX7FrDmtdgJQ",
    "title": "Alì Chiesa S  Agata Preghiera per devozione Padre Serafino",
    "description": "",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GMizgWpyt2k/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GMizgWpyt2k/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/GMizgWpyt2k/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

could someone explain me, please
Really Thank you!!
ps. sorry for the second huge code quote

Answer (score 2):

What a coincidence... I just needed this a few days ago :) Here's the code I used:

```
<?php
    $playlistID = ''; // The Playlist ID for your 'uploads'-playlist.
    $videofile = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=10&playlistId=' . $playlistID;
    $json = file_get_contents($videofile);
    $json = preg_replace('/^\xEF\xBB\xBF/', '', $json);
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key == "items") {
            echo "<table class='vtable'>";
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($array["items"]); $i = $i + 1) {
                $id = $array["items"][$i]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'];
                $thumbnail = $array["items"][$i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'];
                $title = $array["items"][$i]['snippet']['title'];
                $description = $array["items"][$i]['snippet']['description'];
                // do some stuff with the variables
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply!!
the for line gives error:
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: That's weird... Seems you're getting an object instead of an array.. try replacing all the `$array["x"]` parts with  `$array->x`

Answer (score 0):

1) Make a HTTP request from PHP to get the JSON data as a string. Do this using cURL, a library like Guzzle, or a built-in function like file_get_contents(). Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
$youtube_api_string = file_get_contents("http://your_api_url");
```

2) Convert that string into a standard object using

```
$api_result = json_decode($youtube_api_string);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

3) Write a loop to assemble your search results into usable YouTube URLs

```
$youtube_urls = []; 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($api_result->items); $i++) {
    $video = $api_result->items[$i];
    array_push($youtube_urls, ["url" => "http://youtube.com/watch?v=" . $video->id->videoId, "title" => $video->snippet->title ]);
}
```

From here, you should be able to loop through the `$youtube_urls` variable to generate the list of videos on your channel on your site.